# AWS SAM samconfig.toml file not picking up the custom environment using --config-env

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-sam, toml

Working on a SAM application where I have multiple environments. I am using samconfig.toml configuration file to pass environment variables. It works fine when I use default environment such as

```
[default.local_start_api.parameters]
docker_network="host"
parameter_overrides ="TableName=LocalTable Enviroment=local
```

But when I try to package the sam application for dev using `sam package --config-env dev`:

```
[dev.package.parameters]
s3_bucket="mydev-bucket"
template_file="template.yaml"
output_template_file="packaged.yaml"
```

I get `**"Error: Missing option '--s3-bucket'."**` even though I am providing the `s3-bucket` parameter.
Also if I change `[dev.package.parameters]` to `[default.package.parameters]` and `sam package`, it works.

Only giving the error in case of custom environment `dev`.

Comment: `s3_bucket` refers to the "Deployment s3 bucket".  This is where sam cli will store the versions of your stacks that you create. You shouldnt be using this param to pass values to your template.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Only difference is that I have the following at top in the samconfig.toml file
version=0.1